# changing focus to another field using laravel livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Is it possible to set the focus to another field from laravel livewire without using any js code.

```
input wire:model="sku" wire:keydown.enter="getProductInfo" type="text">
```

I am trying to get the product info when user type the sku and press enter. If it find the details, the focus must go to the last field. So, is it possible without using any external JavaScript.

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem will increase your chances of getting good answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need an event to achieve that. emit an event from your getProductInfo function. like this :

```
$this->emit('change-focus-other-field') //any unique event name you want
```

Then catch this event in your livewire component blade. and do whatever you want. (in your case specifically. focus the field via jQuery. I'm assuming you have imported jQuery in your project)

```
@push('scripts')
<script>
   window.livewire.on('change-focus-other-field', function () {
        $("#field-you-want-to-focus").focus();
    });

</script>
@endpush
```

Comment: to achieve hack. hmm maybe.